# Backbone insert value in URL from inputfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to get a data request from a API using the value of a input field that's inside a template I'm rendering. But the template gets rendered at the bottom and the URL at the top so I'm getting a `undefined` back.

[This is the fiddle I'm working on at the moment](http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/73/)

```
var MoviesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function () {
        return "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=" + value
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.results;
    }
});

var value = $('form#autocomplete-remote input').val();
```

I want to do a data request when there's a keyUp on the input field and then it should add the value from the input field to the URL, that way I should be a step closer to a autocomplete feature.

**Small update**

If I remove the form and inputfield from the template and put in the HTML I can get value of the inputfield in the url. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/74/) This does give me a small problem since the input field is now out of the view, how do I trigger a event from it?

If this is a good way to go, I "only" need to fetch the collection on a keyUp event.

**Another small update**

Changing the load order of the scripts I now do render the value from the inputfield from the template. Now only to hook it up to the keyUp. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/78/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/dxpowx27/76/

I prefer to use `blur` but you can change it back to `keyup`

```
var MoviesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function () {
        return "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=" + this.query;
    },
    setQuery:function(q){
        this.query = q;
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.results;
    }
});

var myCollection = new MoviesCollection();

MoviesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (opts) {
        this.collection = opts.collection;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($("#search_template").html(), {});
        this.el.html(template);
    },

    events: {
        'blur input#search_input': 'doSearch'
    },

    doSearch: function (event) {
        var that = this;
        this.collection.setQuery($(event.currentTarget).val());
        this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
            alert("Fetch Complete : " + that.collection.length);
        });
    }
});

var search_view = new MoviesView({
    el: $("#search_container"),
    collection:myCollection
});
```

Comment: Thanks again ;)! Hopefully I can find out a way to iterate through every JSON result and show the `original_title` in list. Instead of the full JSON output I have now > http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/88/ I've been googling and finding it has something to do with the `_each` template.

Comment: Could you give a example how you would show the the results in a template?

Comment: http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/how-to-use-templates-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/